# Python subprocess export environment variables (which use other environment variable)

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables, export

I want to replicate the following bash export command in Python:

```sh
export my_shell=$SHELL
```

If I execute the above command in bash and echo after that:

```sh
echo $my_shell  
/bin/bash
```

How do this in Python? I know we can use export command (which does not use environment variable) using `os.environ()` like following:

```py
import os
os.environ['my_shell'] = "my_shell_string"
```

but how to pass *another* environment variable (in this case: `$SHELL`) as an input when exporting like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a value from `os.environ` dictionary as rvalue as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
print(f"SHELL: {os.environ['SHELL']}")
os.environ['my_shell'] = os.environ['SHELL']
print(f"my_shell: {os.environ['my_shell']}")
```